# Click events from views inside MergeAdapter items only fired after scrolling

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm currently using [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) in my app and I'm facing an issue.

So I have this listview with different parts. The first ones or static views added to the MergeAdapter. They are directly added without activating/deactivating them.

Then I'm adding other adapters to my `MergeAdapter` and hiding them straight away with `setActive()`. These are filled asynchronously but added before `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`. So I'm doing this for each adapter:

1. add the adapter to the `MergeAdapter` with `adapter.addAdapter(subAdapter)`
2. hide it with `adapter.setActive(subAdapter, false)`
3. when the data is fetch, add the retrieved items to the subAdapter, `subAdapter.addItems(items)` and then show the adapter with `adapter.setActive(subAdapter, true)`

Everything is working perfectly and my view is looking good except one thing. I've got a few buttons in the top views from the `MergeAdapter`. The click behaviour is wrong. Sometimes the click events get only fired after scrolling the `ListView`. I've noticed it only happen if I play with the `setActive()` function. If I comment every `setActive()` calls, the issue can't be reproduced.
If I click multiple times then scroll, as many clicks are fired.

Here is some screenshots. The static views are the image and the view with the 4 buttons. Then the dynamic part is the adapters after (biography, last played on and best tracks)

UPDATE:
I've managed to (sort of) fix it by calling subAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() after activating each of them. It's still hacky and doesn't work every time.

UPDATE:
I think this should be covered by the library given that:

> Note, though, that you can modify the underlying adapters. So, for
>   example, if you add a CursorAdapter to the MergeAdapter, and you
>   requery() the Cursor, the changes should be reflected via the
>   MergeAdapter to whatever AdapterView the MergeAdapter is connected to.

[image: top of the list]
[image: bottom of the list]

Comment: Create a sample project that reproduces the problem, then [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/issues) supplying that demonstration code (and steps to reproduce the conditions), so that I can research your problem.

Comment: damn i can't reproduce it in a sample -.-

Comment: There's a fighting chance that the issue lies in something that you're doing with your original code, more so than the `MergeAdapter` itself. That's part of the reason why I ask for a reproducible sample -- if *you* can't reproduce it, *I* haven't a prayer of doing so.

Comment: I totally agree. I just thought it was related to the MergeAdapter as I could solve it by commenting the setActive() part. I'll keep you updated. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: @CommonsWare it was an issue on my end you were right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, my dodging a bullet seems fitting, given that it's the Fourth of July holiday here in the US. :-) Glad to hear that you have it working!

Comment: haha yeah forgot about that! Have a nice day mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually specific to my project. While the content was being fetched and filled, I was showing a screen containing a ProgressBar over the hidden content. The moment when I was showing the content and the one when the data was retrieved were colliding. Technically, the `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` on the screen view was happening at a bad time with the `mergeadapter.setActive()` command.

Anyway, good times! Thanks @CommonsWare