# Click events not triggering MergeAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, commonsware-cwac

I'm having a similar issue described in [Click events from views inside MergeAdapter items only fired after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467472/click-events-from-views-inside-mergeadapter-items-only-fired-after-scrolling). I have the following in a list (using MergeAdapter).

```
----------
View (with buttons)
----------
List 1 empty-state view
----------
List 1 (populated via network call)
----------
List 2 Header view
----------
List 2 (populated via network call)
----------
```

The view has 3 buttons that can be clicked, though they don't register clicks unless the ListView scrolls. I can tap all 3 buttons, scroll, and I'll see 3 events fired simultaneously.

The List 1 empty view is shown/hidden depending on whether the server returns results.

This issue seems to be related to either hiding the List 1 Empty View or something else related to the loading of data in the other 2 adapters, as the issue occurs after populating the 2 adapters (from network call results) but not if I comment out the loading/networking portion.

This is the method to set up my list initially (pre-api calls):

```
private void setup() {
    mAdapter = new MergeAdapter();

    mButtonsView = new EventDetailsRow(getActivity());
    mButtonsView.setOnCallClickListener(v -> mPresenter.onCallClicked());
    mButtonsView.setOnEmailClickListener(v -> mPresenter.onEmailClicked());
    mButtonsView.setOnCalendarClickListener(v -> mPresenter.onCalendarClicked());
    mButtonsView.setOnAddPhoneNumberClickListener(v -> mPresenter.onAddPhoneNumberClicked());
    mAdapter.addView(mButtonsView);

    mList1Adapter = new List1Adapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());
    mAdapter.addAdapter(mList1Adapter);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    mList1EmptyView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_calendar_events_none, null);
    mAdapter.addView(mList1EmptyView);

    View list2Header = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_activity_feed_header, null);
    mAdapter.addView(list2Header);

    mList2Adapter = new List2Adapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());
    mAdapter.addAdapter(mList2Adapter);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I'm populating List 1 with the following:

```
public void appendList1Items(Collection<? extends Items> items) {
    mList1Adapter.addAll(items);
    mList1Adapter.sort((lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getDate().compareTo(rhs.getDate()));
    mList1Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mAdapter.setActive(mCalendarEventsNoneView, false);
}
```

Populating list 2 is similar to above.

Am I misusing the MergeAdapter? Is there an additional call such as `notifyDatasetChanged` I need to call after loading data? Or is there likely something more complex going on here?

Comment: "hiding the List 1 Empty View" -- there is nothing to support hiding in `MergeAdapter`. How are you doing this?

Comment: Must be misunderstanding the concept of "active." I believe the intent to hide was `mAdapter.setActive(mCalendarEventsNoneView, false);` (I am troubleshooting somebody else's code). From the documentation/Readme - `Inactive pieces do not contribute to the contents, removing them entirely from the ListView (or wherever you are using this).`

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry. I am not aware of any problems here, insofar as I am not really involved in anything to do with the contents of the rows themselves. I'd need a sample project that reproduces the problem to really do much for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll see if I can reproduce. I look forward to posting back here with a "can't reproduce, must be my code!" sort of response :)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to reproduce with a simple example. Due to time constraints, I had to abandon MergeAdapter and use a custom adapter. Not saying this is a bug in the library by any stretch. To be candid I was stumped on troubleshooting.

Comment: `MergeAdapter` isn't designed to be the be-all and end-all for complex adapters. It's there for light scenarios. Anything complicated probably deserves a custom adapter implementation. So, you're probably in a good place anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the words of encouragement :)